# Time intervals between resightings of several individuals

Tags: r, dataframe, tapply

In R, I need to calculate several time interval variables between resightings of marked individuals. I have a dataset similar to this:

```
ID Time     Day    Month  
a    11.15   13     6  
a    12.35   13     6
a    10.02   14     6 
a    19.30   15     6
a    20.46   15     6
.
.
.     
b    11.12    8    7
etc
```

In which each `ID` represents a different animal marked for individual recognition, and each row contains the date and time in which it was relocated.

For each individual, I'd need to calculate the number of days each animal was observed, the mean and standard deviation of the number of relocations per day, and the mean and standard deviation of the days elapsed between relocations (including 0 days between observations on the same day.

Ideally, I need to obtain a data frame such this:

```
ID N.Obs N.days mean.Obs.per.Day  m.O.D.sd  mean.days.elapsed mde.sd     
a   27        7    4.2                1.1      1.5              0.5   
b   32        5    3.4                0.4      3.2              0.7
c   17        6    4.4                0.2      4.5              1.2     
d   etc
```

I've been doing it in  using the tapply function and transferring the results to an Excel, but I am sure there must be a relatively simple code which could help me to ignite the process in R.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has requested to aggregate 6 statistics per `ID`. Four of them can by directly aggregated by grouping by `ID`. Two (`mean.Obs.per.Day` and `m.O.D.sd`) need to be grouped by date and `ID` first.

Unfortunately, the time stamps are split up in three different fields, `Time`, `Day`, and `Month` with the year missing. As four of the statistics are based on dates, we need to construct a `Date` column which combines `Day`, `Month`, and a dummy year.

The code below utilises the `data.table` and `lubridate` packages for efficiency.

```
library(data.table)

# coerce to data.table and add Date column
setDT(DF)[, Date := lubridate::make_date(, Month, Day)]

# aggregate by ID, 
# use temporary variable to hold the day differences between resightings
agg_per_id <- DF[, {
  tmp <- as.numeric(diff(Date))
  .(N.Obs = .N, N.days = uniqueN(Date), 
    mean.days.elapsed = mean(tmp), 
    mde.sd = sd(tmp))
} , by = ID]

# aggregate by Date and ID
agg_per_day_and_id <- DF[, .N, by = .(ID, Date)][
  , .(mean.Obs.per.Day = mean(N), m.O.D.sd = sd(N)), by = ID]

# join partial results
result <- agg_per_day_and_id[agg_per_id, on = "ID"]

# reorder columns (for comparison with expected result)
setcolorder(result, c("ID", "N.Obs", "N.days", "mean.Obs.per.Day", 
                      "m.O.D.sd", "mean.days.elapsed", "mde.sd"))
result
```

> ```
>    ID N.Obs N.days mean.Obs.per.Day  m.O.D.sd mean.days.elapsed    mde.sd
> 1:  a     5      3         1.666667 0.5773503               0.5 0.5773503
> 2:  b     1      1         1.000000        NA               NaN        NA
> ```

Note that the figures differ from the expected result of the OP due to different input data.

#### Data

As far as provided by the OP

```
DF <- readr::read_table(
"ID   Time     Day    Month  
  a    11.15   13     6  
  a    12.35   13     6
  a    10.02   14     6 
  a    19.30   15     6
  a    20.46   15     6
  b    11.12    8    7"
)
```